# Viewing Selenium Scripts in Jenkins Server

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I am using Jenking to run my selenium scripts on a remote server. My question is "Is there any way to visually see my scripts running on the server? I mean on an actual browser when scripts are running in Jenkins?"

Comment: Have you tried taking a screenshot? What happens when you do?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot visually see a browser running on ubuntu server but apart from that you can run a headless browser and log everything to see the progress of your scripts running on server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, either use a Sauce labs account, or just run [tightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/intro.php) server on the remote system, which runs a vnc server in a "[Java Viewer](http://www.tightvnc.com/licensing-jviewer.php)"  and by setting a "readonly password" to the server, you can open a browser and using the java viewer, basically you can watch the session and you can even "scale" the size of the desktop just like Sauce Labs can do.